# c# dllImport unresolved external symbol

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I am attempting to create a dll, and call the function from a c# application.

my code is as follows:

header.h

```
#define DllItem __declspec( dllimport )
class DllItem Access
{
public:

    Access();
    ~Access();

    bool open();

}
```

.cpp

```
#include "header.h"


void openTracker()
{
    Access access;

    access.open();
}
```

c#

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharp
{
    class Access
    {

        [DllImport("Access.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void openTracker();




        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            openTracker();
        }
    }
}
```

When I build the dll, i am getting unresolved external symbol errors on the __declspec( dllimport ). what am I missing in the function?

I have followed a tutorial, so may have made some errors. Is this the correct way to go about this?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the dll as reference in teh c# project?

Comment: When you use dllimport then you promise that the *implementation* of the class is located in another module.  Maybe you did write that code in another DLL and correctly used dllexport, it seems unlikely.  If you did then you forgot to tell the linker about it, it needs to link the import library of that other DLL.

Comment: ah, I had a x64 lib linked, when it should have been 32. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Is that all your code? Where is Access::open function definition?

From [Using dllimport and dllexport in C++ Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/81h27t8c.aspx)

> You must provide the definitions of all such members in the same program. Otherwise, a linker error is generated

I hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: As above, i stupidly had a x64 lib linked instead of the 32. Thanks for the link though, definitely helpful.